Shopify order line item fulfillment service do not match product fulfillment service
I have created location and fulfillment service for my app, also I have products which are using the fulfillment service but when I make an order the order line item fulfillment service is set to manual and my app never gets fulfillment requests. Please see below data retrieved form the Shopify store
App location
{
        "id": 75479810300,
        "name": "LocationName",
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "city": null,
        "zip": null,
        "province": null,
        "country": "US",
        "phone": null,
        "created_at": "2024-05-26T14:34:50+03:00",
        "updated_at": "2024-05-26T14:34:50+03:00",
        "country_code": "US",
        "country_name": "United States",
        "province_code": null,
        "legacy": true,
        "active": true,
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Location/75479810300",
        "localized_country_name": "United States",
        "localized_province_name": null
    }

Fulfillment service
{
        "id": 62924095740,
        "name": "FulfillmentService",
        "email": null,
        "service_name": "FulfillmentService",
        "handle": "service123",
        "fulfillment_orders_opt_in": true,
        "include_pending_stock": false,
        "provider_id": null,
        "location_id": 75479810300,
        "callback_url": "https://app.url/fulfilment_service",
        "tracking_support": true,
        "inventory_management": true,
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ApiFulfillmentService/62924095740",
        "permits_sku_sharing": false
    }

Product Variant
{
        "id": 45886911709436,
        "product_id": 8570191872252,
        "title": "White / M",
        "price": "23.56",
        "sku": "19-white-m-28",
        "position": 2,
        "inventory_policy": "deny",
        "compare_at_price": null,
        "fulfillment_service": "service123",
        "inventory_management": "service123",
        "option1": "White",
        "option2": "M",
        "option3": null,
        "created_at": "2024-05-26T15:03:21+03:00",
        "updated_at": "2024-05-26T15:04:37+03:00",
        "taxable": true,
        "barcode": null,
        "grams": 463,
        "weight": 463.0,
        "weight_unit": "g",
        "inventory_item_id": 47981355565308,
        "inventory_quantity": 9,
        "old_inventory_quantity": 9,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/45886911709436",
        "image_id": 41346621374716
    }

You can see that product variant has the correct fulfillment service
But when an order is made with the above product variant the fulfillment service i set to manual and my app never gets fulfillment requests
{
                "id": 14123467440380,
                "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/14123467440380",
                "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
                "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                "fulfillment_status": null,
                "gift_card": false,
                "grams": 463,
                "name": "Product - White / M",
                "price": "23.56",
                "price_set": {
                    "shop_money": {
                        "amount": "23.56",
                        "currency_code": "USD"
                    },
                    "presentment_money": {
                        "amount": "23.56",
                        "currency_code": "USD"
                    }
                },
                "product_exists": true,
                "product_id": 8570191872252,
                "properties": [],
                "quantity": 1,
                "requires_shipping": true,
                "sku": "19-white-m-28",
                "taxable": true,
                "title": "Product",
                "total_discount": "0.00",
                "total_discount_set": {
                    "shop_money": {
                        "amount": "0.00",
                        "currency_code": "USD"
                    },
                    "presentment_money": {
                        "amount": "0.00",
                        "currency_code": "USD"
                    }
                },
                "variant_id": 45886911709436,
                "variant_inventory_management": "service123",
                "variant_title": "White / M",
                "vendor": "App",
                "tax_lines": [],
                "duties": [],
                "discount_allocations": []
            }

